# Background image doesn't display on some Androids but does in others

Tags: android, image, background

I am still fairly new to coding and am having an issue with the footer background image on my site:

http://www.midlandspolechampionships.co.uk

I have found that it works fine on Iphones and some Androids.. for example it's ok on a Samsung S3 mini. However I have a Samsung S3 and it doesn't show up on that except when you click a link and then the background shows up around that link (http://www.midlandspolechampionships.co.uk/img/screenshot.png).

This is the same for the Galaxy Note. I don't know about other phones specifically but I just don't really know what to do to fix it. If it was a consistent problem across devices then I could probably more easily figure it out but it seems a bit strange... The header is also a background image and the css is the same as in the footer so I just don't get it!

I coded this a while ago but had to make it live two days ago so started working on it again so I am not as familiar with the code as I was when i wrote it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: do you care for the drawable folders while coding, like drawable.ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xdpi?

Comment: @abid this is a web page not an android app.

Comment: which browser are you using on the various devices? Are you using the stock browser (just called browser)? If so, is it the same in Chrome? Also check the console (you can debug chrome over usb) for any errors, and play around with the CSS. It's working fine on my nexus 7...

Comment: @EdHinchcliffe I have been using Chrome on the devices. I have checked the Android version and they are all the same on the various Samsungs 4.1.2 . It is fine on a Samsung 4 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your page doesn't even validate with http://validator.w3.org/ on my ChromeBook

I think this line may be the main issue.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

X-UA-Compatible is an IE-specific header that can be used to tell modern IE versions to use a specific IE engine to render the page.

Correct it and try validating it again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have taken that line out and it validates now. It hasn't fixed it unfortunately though